# STM32F7 Discovery Board STemWin examples

Tags: stm32, stm32f7

I've tried compiling the included ticker example with the STemWin_HelloWorld project included in STM32CubeF7. Functionally, it works OK but the draws seem to be corrupted.

Take a look at the video I've uploaded onto [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAW7S1B2xCI):

I suspect it as something to do with the configuration of the memory but I cannot be sure. This was compiled using SW4STM32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is taken from the ST forum [here](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32Discovery/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2FSTM32Discovery%2FSTM32F7%20Discovery%20Board%20STemWin%20examples&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D75800084C20D8867EAD444A5987D47BE638E0F&TopicsView=https%3A%2F%2Fmy%2Est%2Ecom%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2FSTM32Discovery%2FAllItems%2Easpx&currentviews=40).

Turns out you have to disable caching by commenting out the line in the main function:

```
CPU_CACHE_Enable();
```